# Programmatic Constraints not working as expected

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I've spent hours trying to hunt down what is preventing my constraints layout from working.  I have a view called `ABSegment` which simply holds a UILabel which should be centered and have equal height and width as its superview.

I'll include the entire class definition of this UIView subview to show what I've done.

```
import UIKit

class ABSegment: UIView {

   let titleLabel = UILabel()

   init(withTitle title: String) {

      titleLabel.text = title
      titleLabel.textAlignment = .center

      super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

      translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      addSubview(titleLabel)

      backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
   }


   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()


      logFrames()
   }


   func logFrames() {
      print("self.frame is \(frame)")
      print("titleLabel.frame is \(titleLabel.frame)")
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }



   override func updateConstraints() {


      logFrames()

      titleLabel.removeConstraints(titleLabel.constraints)

      let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

      let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

      let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

      let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerX, centerY, width, height])

      super.updateConstraints()
   }



}
```

One natural thing to suspect is that I'm not initializing this view with initWithFrame.  Rather, I'm deferring the frame setting until later in the code where these views are constructed.  So code that constructs these don't set the frame.  The frame may be set in Storyboard or like this:

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

      let frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.origin.x + 150, y: view.bounds.origin.y + 200, width: 100, height: 100)
      segment.frame = frame

      segment.layoutSubviews()

   }
```

My understanding is that since I'm calling `segment.layoutSubviews()`, the ABSegment View should have a change to apply the previously activated constraints with a final frame.

There are so many different settings and things to get right in the correct order with no feedback other than not seeing the Label appear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems I see with your code:

1. You are adding and removing constraints every time `updateConstraints` is called.  You only need to set up the constraints once when you create your view.
2. You are setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on `ABSegment` itself.  Don't do this.  This tells *Auto Layout* that you will be specifying the size and location of `ABSegment` using constraints, and you clearly are using a `frame` for this purpose.

---

Here is the refactored code:

```
class ABSegment: UIView {

    let titleLabel = UILabel()

    // Computed property to allow title to be changed
    var title: String {
        set {
            titleLabel.text = newValue
        }
        get {
            return titleLabel.text ?? ""
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupLabel(title: "")
    }

    convenience init(title: String) {

        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        self.title = title
    }

    // This init is called if your view is
    // set up in the Storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupLabel(title: "")
    }

    func setupLabel(title: String) {

        titleLabel.text = title

        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center

        addSubview(titleLabel)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerX, centerY, width, height])
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        logFrames()
    }

    func logFrames() {
        print("self.frame is \(frame)")
        print("titleLabel.frame is \(titleLabel.frame)")
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {            
        super.updateConstraints()            
        logFrames()
    }

}
```

---

Notes:

1. I moved all of the setup of the label into a function called `setupLabel`.  This allows it to be called by both initializers.
2. I added a computed property called `title` to `ABSegment` which allows you to change the `title` at any time with `mysegment.title = "new title"`.
3. I turned `init(withSegment:)` into a *convenience init*.  It calls the standard `init(frame:)` and then sets the `title`.  It is not a common practice to use `withProperty` so I changed it.  You'd create an `ABSegment` with `var segment = ABSegment(title: "some title")`.
4. I had `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` call `setupLabel` so that `ABSegment` can be used with views added in the *Storyboard*.
5. The overrides of `layoutSubviews` and `updateConstraints` were left in to log the frames.  That is all that they do now.

Comment: great!  Indeed setting the auto-resizing mask to constraints was the primary culprit.  I appreciate the additional coding tips you gave as well and the knowledge that the constraints need only be set once when constructing the label.    Part of why i thought the constraints should be recalculated at every 'updateConstraints' is that I was comparing it to `layoutSubviews`.  for layoutSubviews, i feel it is worth having the computed frames be done for each layout pass.

Comment: the root view in a hierarchy may change and then all of the descendent view frames need to calculate new rects at layoutSubviews time.  with constraint revolving, i'm not sure this is also needed.  And so you only need to define/activate the constraints at init time for that view.  So constraints don't share the same semantics.